# how to get Ckeditor output in html web page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ckeditor

```
    <body>
        
        <textarea id="content"></textarea>
        <input id="data" type="text"/>
        <input id="insert" type="button" value="Insert at Cursor"/>
        <div class="container mt-3">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.7/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace('content');
   
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

HOW TO GET THE OUTPUT ANY FORM WITHOUT A DATABASE IAM NEW THIS PLEASE HELP, AND IF YOU COULD ATTACH THE SOURCE CODE IT WILL BE A GREAT HELP.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you need? Is it to use JS to read what the user has typed into the text area? I don’t understand what this could have to do with a database which would normally be accessed through the backend.

Comment: yes, I just want to see what has been typed, like <P>hello</p>

Answer (score 0):

Ckeditor has its own function for that,

```
CKEDITOR.instances['SELECTOR-HERE'].getData();
```